# Translate R lm poly output to Excel equation?

Tags: r, linear-model, excel

I have the results of a lm model and its a so-so fit but now I have to dump it into an Excel file to do predictions. Most of it I get but the POLY factors I don't understand and where there is data it gives me wild predictions.  Obviously, I don't understand how to build the formula using the poly and hope someone can help.

The equation I'm using is:

log(sales) = 14 -4.887log(MSRP) + 4.285 log(Price) + .09075 log(APR+1) +2.042 CashCustomer + 2.125 (CashCustomer)^2 -.0002659 Volume -.00006651(APR) +e

My lm output is:

```
lm(formula = log(autod$Sales) ~ log(MSRP) + log(Price) + log(APR + 
1) + poly(CashCustomer, 2) + (Volume) + APR, data = autod)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.40541 -0.30366  0.02278  0.32354  1.44976 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             1.400e+01  1.386e+00  10.103  < 2e-16 ***
log(MSRP)              -4.887e+00  7.245e-01  -6.746 2.25e-10 ***
log(Price)              4.285e+00  7.160e-01   5.985 1.24e-08 ***
log(APR + 1)            9.075e-02  1.867e-02   4.861 2.63e-06 ***
poly(CashCustomer, 2)1  2.042e+00  5.689e-01   3.590 0.000432 ***
poly(CashCustomer, 2)2  2.125e+00  4.859e-01   4.375 2.11e-05 ***
Volume                 -2.659e-04  1.151e-04  -2.310 0.022062 *  
APR                    -6.651e-05  2.776e-05  -2.396 0.017659 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4642 on 171 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4893,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4684 
F-statistic: 23.41 on 7 and 171 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: The coefficients you quote in the text do not seem to bear much resemblance to the ones from R. Also, why not use R to do the predictions?

Comment: Because someone wants to have it in Excel to run against test data and honestly I'm not sure how to do this yet.... (R newbie).  In fact, the original assignment was supposed to be done in Excel but I challenged myself to do it in R.

Comment: By default R uses an orthogonal coding for polynomials and not the raw coding that you assumed. Checking out this discussion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999900/poly-in-lm-difference-between-raw-vs-orthogonal